# preform ontouch over two ImageView in overlay?

Tags: android

My problem is when i click on the intersection area both preform click .

I need one Image preform click ,then when i click on intersection area onTop view only preform click.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    v.performClick();
// ImageView1
if (v.getId() == R.id.Card1) {
        if (!cardflags[0]) {
            Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                    R.anim.move_up12);
            v.clearAnimation();
            v.setAnimation(an);
        }
    }
// ImageView2
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Card2) {
        if (!cardflags[1]) {
            Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                    R.anim.move_up10);
            v.clearAnimation();
            v.setAnimation(an);
        }
return false;
}
```

[image: Two ImageView in overlay]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    v.performClick();
// ImageView1
if (v.getId() == R.id.Card1) {
        if (!cardflags[0]) {
            Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                    R.anim.move_up12);
            v.clearAnimation();
            v.setAnimation(an);
        }
    }
// ImageView2
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Card2) {
        if (!cardflags[1]) {
            Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                    R.anim.move_up10);
            v.clearAnimation();
            v.setAnimation(an);
        }
return true;
}
```

The event won't be passed to other listeners when you return `true`